# I need a discord bot, that sends a welcome message to every new comer in a server

Tags: discord, bots

I'm looking for a Discord bot, That can be able to pick new joiners in the a discord server and send them welcome message to there inbox. Thank you

Comment: Creating a member Join event will help

Answer (score 0):

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=join#discord.on_member_join

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    member.author.send("Welcome")
```